# Convert recursively all layer II mp3's to layer III and also update ID3

Tags: shell, audio, mp3, converters

I am in the situation described in http://nerdbynature.de/s9y/?316. I have a file

```
$ file foo.mp3
foo.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer II, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

and I want to turn `layer II` to `layer III` and as well `ID3 version 2.3.0` to `ID3 version 2.4.0`. For a single file, the described way works just perfect.

```
$ mv foo.{mp3,mp2}
$ lame --mp2input foo.mp2 foo.mp3
$ mid3iconv -d foo.mp3
$ rm foo.mp2
$ file foo.mp3
foo.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```

1. How do I now write a (preferably shell) script that runs recursively through a huge folder containing music, and check each file. If it uses `layer II`, turn this into `layer III` using `lame`, and if it uses `ID3 version 2.3.0`, turn this into `ID3 version 2.4.0` using mid3iconv.
2. Also, how do I assure that I am not loosing quality (I see above that the input was 192kbps while the output is only 128kbps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started

```
find -name '*.mp3' | while read ip
do
  file "$ip" | grep -q '2.4.0.*III' && continue
  ib=${ip%.*}
  ffmpeg -i "$ip" -q:a 0 "$ib"-iii.mp3
done
```

- Noticed I have not used
  [`-print0`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), might be a good idea.
- [`-q:a 0`](https://superuser.com/a/354662) will maintain the quality.
- FFmpeg defaults to Layer III codec when you use output extension `.mp3`
- FFmpeg writes
  [2.4.0 metadata](https://superuser.com/a/453133)
  by default

Comment: thanks for you suggestion! I wonder why it is actually better to use ffmpeg -- I cannot trivially install it on ubuntu. Can I just replace the ffmpeg line by the code I used above? Or are there any other drawbacks?

Comment: @ChristianStump I think on Ubuntu you can use `avconv` as a drop in replacement

Comment: it does work now, thanks! I have two more questions there: 1) is `file "$ip" | grep -q '2.4.0.*III' && continue` ensuring that it is processed if EITHER of the two conditions is satisfied? 2) I processed some test files and see that the input is 192 kbps while the output is 64 kbps only (using `file foo.mp3`) -- at the same time, the file size increased by a factor of 1.3 . Is that the supposed behaviour?

Comment: @ChristianStump ffmpeg will run unless both conditions are met. If you are having trouble with the rate you can use `-b:a 192k` instead

Comment: Thanks again! (in case others wanna do the same:) I also tried 192k but that decreased the quality significantly.